# What's a decently optimized way to insert elements into a page using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to do a little bit of code optimization for an application I've made... Essentially right now I have a container like so...

```
<div class="Container"></div>
```

This container is already in the DOM. I then want to insert data into this container in the form of a list.... I want to do something like this....

```
var list = $("<ul class='DataList'></ul>");
var ListElements = PopulateMeWithALargeList();
for(var i = 0; i < ListElements.length; i++)
{
    $(ListElements[i]).appendTo(list);
}
$(list).appendTo(".Container");
```

Where PopulateMeWithLargeList is just a function that will get a large (about 500 entries) array of strings and return it.

I have a feeling that this would be the same as me inserting the elements directly onto the rendered page, so would it be better if I formed it all into 1 string and then inserted that 1 string into the Container?

Comment: Nope, you're appending to an element that exists only in memory, assuming you didn't put the `list` element anywhere before after the loop has completed, so it's fine.

Comment: Of course, jQuery accepts an array of DOM nodes, so you could probably just do `$("<ul />", {"class" : "DataList"}).append(ListElements)`

Comment: Code clarity is preferable to premature optimization. Are you actually experiencing a visual slowdown? Because I wouldn't think 500 elements would make any modern browser sweat, regardless of how you insert them.

Comment: @JayArby the example I gave was just that, an example. The current state of the application displays hundreds but will eventually displays thousands at a time given the proper amount of data logging.

However, yes right now there is some load issues present in the iOS Application version. I'm using Phonegap to develop the application cross-platforms, which the lag is only really present in the iOS version. So I'm just trying to do some minor optimization in various departments.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
$('<ul class="DataList">')
    .append(PopulateMeWithALargeList())
    .appendTo('.Container');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd line since there doesn't seem to be a reason for casting each element as a specific jquery object:

```
$(ListElements[i]).appendTo(list);
```

Unless you were doing something else that required each list element have the jquery chain available right away in your loop, you can do:

```
list.append(ListElements[i]);
```

Using a string buffer will be faster. An array buffer will be even faster. But as others have pointed out, this is an unlikely bottleneck at the current numbers. FWIW, always call any jquery methods as few times as possible.